# Shell Script: Read line in file

Tags: shell, scripting, sh, cut

I have a file **paths.txt**:

```
/my/path/Origin/.:your/path/Destiny/.
/my/path/Origin2/.:your/path/Destiny2/.
/...
/...
```

I need a Script **CopyPaste.sh** using file paths.txt to copy all files in OriginX to DestinyX

Something like that:

```
 #!/bin/sh

while read line
do
        var= $line | cut --d=":" -f1
        car= $line | cut --d=":" -f2
        cp -r var car

done < "paths.txt"
```

Comment: The syntax is `var=$(command)`, while you are doing `var = command`, which is interpreted as "execute `var` command with `=` and `command` parameters".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use translate : `tr` command & apply `cp` command in the same go!

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line; do
  cp `echo $line | tr ':' ' '`
done < "paths.txt"
```

Comment: if its backtick related err for non-ksh shells, you can try with

cp $(echo $line | tr ':' ' ')

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [**command substitution**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to get command's output into a shell variable:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line
do
        var=`echo $line | cut --d=":" -f1`
        car=`echo $line | cut --d=":" -f2`
        cp -r "$var" "$car"
done < "paths.txt"
```

Though your script can be simplified using `read -d`:

```
while read -d ":" var car; do
  cp -r "$var" "$car"
done < "paths.txt"
```

Comment: Seems like $ is missing in line : cp -r "var" "car"
 AND I don't get correct values using 'while read -d .... "