# Shell sed command

Tags: bash, shell, sed, tr

I have paths.txt like:

```
pathO1/:pathD1/
pathO2/:pathD2/
...
pathON/:pathDN/
```

How can I 'sed' insert ' * ' after each pathOX/ ?

The script is:

```
while read line
do
    cp $(echo $line | tr ':' ' ')   

done < "paths.txt"
```

substituted by:

```
while read line
do
    cp $(echo $line | sed 's/:/* /1')   

done < "paths.txt"
```

Comment: You cannot use more than one char in `tr`. To do so you need `sed` or another one. Also, what are you exactly trying to do? `cp $line $line_with*`?

Comment: Thanks fedorqui, I fixed the problem replacing 'tr' with 'sed':

cp $(echo $line | sed 's/:/* /1')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a similar question to which you asked earlier: [Shell Script: Read line in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478334/shell-script-read-line-in-file/21480099?noredirect=1#comment32630854_21480099)

Just apply the trick of removing additional '*' before appliying tr like:

```
cp $(echo $line | sed 's/\*//1' | tr ':' '* ')
```

Comment: I want to remove the ' * ' from paths.txt (write manually in the text file pathOX/:pathDX/) and with 'sed' command insert the ' * ' at the final of each origin path. Thanks

Comment: cp $(echo $line | sed 's/:/* /1')

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line
do
    path=`echo "$line" | sed 's/:/ /g'`
    cmd="cp $path"
    echo $cmd
    eval $cmd        
done < "./paths.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure shell

```
while IFS=: read -r p1 p2
do
  cp $p1 "$p2"
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty awk one-liner without loop to do the job:

```
awk -F: '$1="cp "$1' paths.txt
```

this will output:

```
cp /home/Documents/shellscripts/Origen/* /home/Documents/shellscripts/Destino/
cp /home/Documents/shellscripts/Origen2/* /home/Documents/shellscripts/Destino2/
...
```

if you want the cmds to get executed:

```
awk -F: '$1="cp "$1' paths.txt|sh
```

I said it quick & dirty, because:

- the format must be `path1:path2`
- your path cannot contain special letters (like space) or `:`

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. I try to remove the " * " from path1 in order to have: path1:path2 and do not have path1/*:path2

Comment: I still didn't understand quite clearly what do you want. you can try to change the  `-F:` to `-F'\*:'` and give it a try. I didn't test though. @user3228279